# Is it possible to extend/insert a CSS property value

Tags: html, css, wordpress

My question may be a little confusing, my css skills are moderate at best but none the less I'll do my best to try and explain. So my question is as follows;

> ***Is it possible to insert/extend a CSS property value?***

An example of what im trying to achieve can be found within the snippet below;

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrap {
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  float:left;
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 80%;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}


/* --- original element... --- */

.original {
  background-image: url(http://imageshack.com/a/img631/8360/WuQwuf.jpg);
}


/* --- What I'm After --- */

.sourced {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 100%), url(http://imageshack.com/a/img631/8360/WuQwuf.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box original"></div>
  <div class="box sourced"></div>
</div>
```

Some background of my intended application, I have a WP installation running Avada wp theme. Within the theme a div element is built with a css image background, but the nature of this theme minizes the need for heavy coding. This is where I hit a wall as the element can only be overidden with css. But, I want to refrain from doing so as the image is dynamically inserted from the wp image library to keep the images responsive; I.e. desktop size, tablet, mobile, etc.

From what I understand overiding the css would mean hardcoding the URL into the stylesheet breaking the responsitivity.

> **My Research**
>
> I spent some time digging around the web but the solutions I came across seemed more difficult, or a little to hacky for practical use. After further digging I was able to stumble accross this [CSS Extend Rule](https://tabatkins.github.io/specs/css-extend-rule/).
>
> However, my understanding of this article is that using `@extend` would simply chain on a new rule to an exisiting class, providing the rule is computed.

The answer may be super simple, but I have never encountered a need for this before. Any help is much appreciated.

> **EDIT - THU 8 JUN 2017 09:52**
>
> Due to the nature of this project being a little time sensitive I have hardcoded the Property and it's Value, breaking the responsitivity. This will not be a long term fix and I will be sourcing a better solution. To all that arrive late I will be monitoring this question for the forseeable future, so feel free to try to answer.

```
/* -- Overide Currently in Use -- */
.post-content #main-hero {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 100%), url("https://www.url.com/image") !important;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean like an overlay over the image?

Comment: You could do this in js, but not in pure css as far as I know

Comment: @Martijn correct, I'd like to do it via css rather than creating a whole new images as I may have other uses for the same effect.

Comment: @gaynorvader I'm open to all options, could you elaborate? Sadly my .js skills are even more lacking... :(

Answer (score 2):

If you want to overlay the image with another element with e.g. a gradient or background color, you can 'cheat'

```css
 /* original css */
    .original {
        background-image: url(http://imageshack.com/a/img631/8360/WuQwuf.jpg);
    }

    /* extra css */
    .original{
        position: relative;
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
    }
    .original:before{
        position: absolute;
        content : "I am placed over the image";
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.9) 100%);
    }
```

```html
<div class="original"></div>
```

Comment: See I thought I could take the same route, but this would mean the written content and other elements within the div would also be tinted... due to the nature of it being an overlay...

Comment: You might want to add the gradient to `.original` and then use `:before` with the image as background. Can't think of other solutions of the top of my head

Comment: Sadly this didn't work either, it just laid the image over all the content.

Comment: I like your enthusiasm but can you z-index a psudo selector? i.e. `:before` I don't think you can, can you?

Answer (score 1):

You don´t need any js to do this. I can do it with css. I´ll use these technique every days!! :) Pass inline css **(only background-image property)** to the element you need to change dynamically background image.

```
<div class="wrap">
     <div class="box" style="background-image: url(your/image/url.jpg)"></div>
     <div class="box" style="background-image: url(your/image1/url.jpg)"></div>
</div>
```

And in your css you´ll only need this code lines:

```
.box {
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
    padding-top: 80%;

    // Important to keep
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
```

}

If you keep the above code you´ll have the responsiveness on your images.

Comment: Under normal circumstances I'd totally agree, but the nature of the theming engine is very 'anti' this soultion. I'd like to avoid hard code edits in this case as it would break responsitivity.

Comment: I'm referring to the way php pulls the correct images for the specific devices, hard coding this would negate this functionality.